# Validation in Java

Tags: java, regex, validation

How can I make user name and password  (other fields like name, lastname) validator for registration in java? The best way will be probably using some regexp. The allowed characters should be probably only letters, numbers and "-" or "*" and also letters like řščťž ... 
The validation of each field will be probably very similar. 


Input is: String validatedFideld, allowed characters - some of theese: a-z, A-Z,-,*,řščžýě... (== letters with diacritic)
Output is: true (= valid), false (= not vallid).

Comment: I tryed it with ifs and elses its enought for login and password, where I not allow the characters řščž..., for fields where I use diacritic just enumerate the signs which are allowed řščť.., but I think its quite silly way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use regular expressions. `\w` matches all letters (not only English letters), digits and `-`. So, `(\w|-)+` can match what you want.

Personally I do not like when applications try to limit my possibilities for choosing password. Using special characters in password make it more secure, so limiting this is a bad practice. But you can indeed limit username or other fields.

Comment: Great, I'll consider the password thing. I want to avoid this in password: < script > or <html>, so the easiest way is just denny all and allow just what I mentioned. I newer used anything else in password than letters, numbers, -,_ and I thing you can make quite powerfull password from it.

Comment: I tested it and your response is wrong, cause \w doesn't work with řšč.. I tryed it in http://java-regex-tester.appspot.com/

Comment: !!!!!!!!!!!!!!! One way to make it works is: (\w|-|ř|Ř|č|Č|<there just must be all letters from alphabeth with diacritics>)